# Generate a jar with embedded Jetty using maven jetty plugin?

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I use the `mvn jetty:run` goal from the [maven jetty plugin](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin) to start my web application project, built using maven.

Now I want to create a fat jar with embedded Jetty so that I will be able to start my app using `java -jar`.

Is there a way to use the maven jetty plugin to generate a fat jar with embedded Jetty?

Comment: include jetty dependency in your application and start in main method. you can fat jar the jetty and other jars using maven shade plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MarianP already answered your question in the comment.

Add your jetty dependencies in your pom.xml

```
<!-- jetty dependencies -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
  <version>9.2.5.v20141112</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>9.2.5.v20141112</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
  <artifactId>websocket-server</artifactId>
  <version>9.2.5.v20141112</version>
</dependency>
```

Add the shade plugin like so:

```
  <!-- maven shade plugin, executable uber Jar -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <mainClass>YourMainClassHere</mainClass>
            </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
              <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
            </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
              <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Then add your server/client from your main()

Comment: how to do this without any java code? I do not have any java file. mvn jetty:run still works great as static files web server. But I have no class with a main method.